# i do not understand the comparison

Tags: java

Im currently going over MIT courseware for java and am unsure why there is a piece of code involved. I tried removing the code to determine if it is necessary and it kept the program from running.

I have two arrays, one is names of runners, the other is their times. the goal is to find the index of the lowest (fastest) time and then also give the person with the second fastest time.    i.e the command prompt will output john is the fastest and kate is the second fastest

the part i am confused about is "secondIndex == -1 ||"   --- why is this here? if i remove it i get the error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

```
public static int getSecondIndex(int[] values) {
    int minIndex = getMinIndex(values);
    int secondIndex = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if(i == minIndex){
            continue;
        }
        if(secondIndex == -1 ||
            values[i] < values[secondIndex]) {
            secondIndex = i;
        }
    }
        return secondIndex;
}
```

Comment: why wouldn't i just put
    int secondIndex = 0; 

and change the test to 
    if(values[i] < values[secondIndex]) {
        secondIndex = i;
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will then evaluate `values[secondIndex]` which does not have an entry at index -1. The `||` short circuits from left to right so in the case of secondIndex = -1, `values[secondIndex]` will never be evaluated.

Comment: What is the rational for not putting
int secondIndex = 0; and changing the test to 

if(values[i] < values[secondIndex]) { 
    secondIndex = i; }

Comment: 0 is a valid array index. -1 is not. this allows you to track all possible array indexes along with knowing when you have yet to find any index. it does not have to be -1. it could be any negative number and still work. alternatively if you want to use zero as your base you would need to use a boolean or some other flag to determine if you have yet to set anything. you could also just record the values instead of the indexes but that's a larger change.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the loop checks if the current runner's time is less than any time found so far, but when it checks the *first* runner there is no "fastest runner so far" to compare to. So the check first makes sure that `secondIndex` has been set at least once before. If it hasn't, the second part of the or statement will never get evaluated (called short-circuit evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's there is because of [how `indexOf` works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29): it can only find things that live on index 0 or higher, so if it *cannot* find anything, it returns -1.

As such, we compare to -1 to see whether or not something was found at all. If it wasn't, we don't need to waste any more time on it:

```
if(thing.indexOf(otherthing) == -1) {
  // the search failed
}
```

if it was, we can use the result to immediately look it by using the result of indexOf as an array index.

Answer (score 0):

This condition (`secondIndex == -1`) is true in the case that `secondIndex` has not yet been found. Remember that since `||` is a short circuit operator, if the first condition is true, the second one will not be evaluated. Therefore, if `secondIndex` is -1, `values[secondIndex]` will never be evaluated (which is good, because doing so would cause the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`).